# HERE maps for JavaScript API: add a waypoint between two stops

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here Maps to create interactive maps.

using the JS api, is there a demo out there to create a way point between two other existing waypoints in a similar fashion as Here WeGo does?

[add waypoint:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q2cf.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples <-------- Refer this! it got waypoint's marking from point to point and other examples needed! hope this helps

Comment: No it doesn't, we have looked in many places for this example or for various examples that may be useful to accomplish this task, but not luck so far, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no demo like this. You could achieve this by combining these examples:

[Simple routing](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b)

[Reverse Geocoding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/reverse-geocode-an-address-from-location)

[Context menu](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/events/context-menu)

[Draggable Marker](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/draggable-marker)

[Custom Marker Icon](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers)

Recently I created simple routing example which adds/removes waypoints on `contextmenu` (right click) event callback. No draggable markers, unfortunately, but maybe it helps.

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0w3sktxp/).

Comment: thank you for your input, we will keep looking into it!